# How to keep the .kube/config tidy after deleting a cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

In Microsoft Windows, I'm finding that as I create and delete AKS clusters that my `.kube/config` file is accumulating context entries for things that I've deleted.

I've tried using the following commands, but afterwards I still find entries for the context in the `.kube/config` file despite the fact that kubectl does NOT list the context anymore.

```
kubectl config delete-context someContextNameHere
kubectl config unset contexts.someContextNameHere
```

Afterwards, using the `kubectl config get-contexts` command does show that they are **gone**, but entries for the deleted context are left behind in the `.kube/config` file.

Currently, my only solution is to delete everything using kubectl and then delete the config file or be brave and try to slice out the entries by hand.

Is there a way of using kubectl to keep this file free of unwanted context entries?

Answer (score 0):

A kubectl config file represents a [`Config`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/config-api/kubeconfig.v1/#Config) kind and comprises 3 main types: `clusters`, `contexts and` users`.

**Be very careful deleting entries; always backup the config before editing**

Managed Kubernetes platforms often add `cluster`,`context` and `user` entries but often don't delete them; it's easier to leave the file polluted with dead entries than to inadvertently delete a needed entry.

> Aside: Are you deleting AKS clusters using the inverse of the tool that creates the clusters? Often times (e.g. Google does this), deletion will delete the relevants kubeconfig entries.

A `context` combines a `cluster`, a `user` and occasionally a `namespace`.

When you delete a `cluster`, you may want to delete any `contexts` that reference it **but** it's possible there could be more than one.

When you delete a `context`, you may want to delete any `users` that it references **but** the `user` may be referenced by more than one `context`.

It is *often* (but **not always**) true that managed kubernetes services (like AKS) create a `context` and `user` for each `cluster` that's created.

So, after forcing you to read the TL;DR ...

```bash
# Backup
# E.g. cp ~/.kube/config ~/.kube/config.$(date +%y%m%d%H%M)

CLUSTER="..."
USER="..."
CONTEXT="..."

kubectl config delete-cluster ${CLUSTER}
kubectl config delete-user ${USER}
kubectl config delete-context ${CONTEXT}
```

- [`kubectl config delete-cluster`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/generated/kubectl_config/kubectl_config_delete-cluster/)
- [`kubectl config delete-user`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/generated/kubectl_config/kubectl_config_delete-user/)

These `kubectl` commands **don't** perform any referential integrity checks on the file so you can easily delete a `cluster` or a `user` that is referenced by multiple contexts.

Found this (haven't used) `kubectl` plugin: [`kubectl-config-cleanup`](https://github.com/B23admin/kubectl-config-cleanup)